# Problems with Xamarin Asynchronous Methods

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin-studio

In the event of a button from my APP I had the following code it worked running on android emulator, but when I passed the app to the phone generates a message the app stopped.

```
    Button buttonPessoasNecessita = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.mybuttonPesNec);
    buttonPessoasNecessita.Click += delegate {
    Service1Client client;
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding () { Name= "basicHttpBinding", MaxReceivedMessageSize = 67108864,};

    binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas() 
    { MaxArrayLength = 2147483646, MaxStringContentLength = 5242880, }; 

    var timeout = new TimeSpan(0,60,60); 
    binding.SendTimeout= timeout; 
    binding.OpenTimeout = timeout; 
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout; 


    client = new Service1Client(binding, new EndpointAddress ("http://engb.uni5.net/Service1.svc")); 

    buttonPessoasNecessita.text = client.envioPessoa();

    };
```

Trying to solve the case thought to use asynchronously, I tried various examples but none became clear to me and I saw that my object 'client' is there a method has a beginenvioPessoa () method and other endenvioPessoa (); Based on this link Easy way to use WCF service with async / await tried to set up a method to consume the web service async way

call the method:

```
 var t = await executeAsync(binding);
```

Method:

```
public async Task<string> executeAsync(BasicHttpBinding binding){

    Service1Client client = new Service1Client(binding, new EndpointAddress ("http://engb.uni5.net/Service1.svc")); 

    var t = Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync (
        ((IService1)client.InnerChannel).BeginenvioPessoa,
        ((IService1)client.InnerChannel).EndenvioPessoa);
    return await t;
}
```

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync(System.IAsyncResult,
>   System.Func)' has some invalid arguments
>   (CS1502)
>
> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'System.IAsyncResult' (CS1503)

Answer (score 0):

Signature is:

```
Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Func<IASyncResult, string> endMethod)
```

so try this instead

```
var t = Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync( 
  ((IService1)client.InnerChannel).BeginenvioPessoa, result =>
    ((IService1)client.InnerChannel).EndenvioPessoa);
```